# Which browsers and versions support directly passing common array-like objects to fn.apply()

Tags: javascript, function, cross-browser, arguments

Which browsers and versions support (Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari, iOS Safari, and Android) the following JavaScript Function `apply()` feature:

```
function foo(){
  alert('foo!');
};

foo.apply(null, arguments);

// OR

foo.apply(null, document.querySelectorAll('div'));
```

ADDED CLARIFICATION:

In the past many browsers required the following:

```
fn.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0));
```

I want to know which browsers and versions will accept this:

```
fn.apply(this, arguments);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @RustyFausak - as you can see, via the compatibility table for `arguments` object use with `apply()`, there is no data on which browser versions it works in (other than Firefox). This does not answer the question I asked.

Comment: @BlueSkies - please folks, read the question. I am not asking which browsers support basic use of `Function.apply()`, I'm asking which browsers and versions support use of the `arguments` object as the second parameter of `apply()`.

Comment: I did read the question. The answer is "all of them".

Comment: Fine. Give me one example that doesn't accept the native `arguments` object, and if you're right, I'll do some research and post an answer. ... *"In the past many browsers required the following:"* Super, if there are "many", you'll have no trouble giving me an example.

Comment: @BlueSkies I know for a fact earlier versions of Safari Desktop and Mobile do not implement the ES5 feature to allow passing array-like objects as the second parameter of array. I also know that Firefox before version 4 does not implement the feature.

Comment: That's just incorrect. I just tested IE6 and FF3. Both work just fine. I can't test Safari at the moment, but I do know it supports it. Now supporting host objects that are array-like is another issue. But `arguments` is native, and works just fine. So when you say you "know for a fact", I think you should back your claim.

Comment: @BlueSkies well it said right in the compat table on MDN that it was Firefox 4+, and because it is a feature standardized as a recommendation in ES5, it would stand to reason that some browsers that don't support all of ES5 would be missing it. Additionally, there are a zillion questions answered on how to pass `arguments`, they point people to `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)` <-- so this whole time, all those people were just doing this for kicks?

Comment: No, not for kicks. It's called cargo cult programming. The ES5 recommendation is to make it apply to any array-like object. But `arguments` was always supported.

Comment: @BlueSkies I threw a test together and ran browserstack's screenshot tool over it - this feature appears to be very well supported indeed (at least for iOS v5+, it doesn't offer lesser versions). Here's the output: http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/a524526d0923ffa3b9a03dd143095d1f67075501

Comment: Yeah, I've never encountered any issues with `arguments` in that position. The MDN could certainly use some updating for clarification.

Comment: @BlueSkies now here's an interesting test of another array-like object that is probably the most commonly applied after `arguments`, `NodeList` objects that are output from `document.querySelectorAll()`. The coverage is waaay worse: http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/4fe809c5398183374fbb4c950a92cf710251ee6e

Comment: Right, that's a host object. It's not native to JavaScript (ECMAScript), but is rather an extension provided by the host environment (the browser). Also, an object like `{0:"foo",1:"bar",length:2}` wouldn't work in old browsers even though it's native. The ECMAScript 3 spec required explicitly that the argument be an Array or Arguments object, otherwise it required a TypeError.

Comment: @BlueSkies - yeah...I know all about host objects and JavaScript (I was a core contributor to MooTools, wrote X-Tag, work at Mozilla, participate in W3 specs, etc). I simply forgot if `arguments` passing in apply() was widely supported in older browser versions, and had trouble finding a source with a definitive compat range for them. When you work for an "evergreen" browser vendor, you tend to lose touch with testing/compat on really old user agents ;)

Comment: @BlueSkies Kangax needs to update his ES5 compat table with an entry for passing array-like objects (not just `arguments`) into `Function.apply()`. It would be really helpful to devs trying to work with common DOM objects like NodeLists and HTMLCollections, etc --> http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/. I'll drop him a line!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out (based on info provided by *Blue Skies* in the question comments above), passing the array-like object `arguments` as the second parameter of `Function.apply()` is well supported in almost all modern browsers.

Unfortunately, support for passing other common, array-like DOM objects, such as `NodeList`, `HTMLCollection`, etc., to `Function.apply()` is spotty. Here's a batch of tests that look for `NodeList` passing support (the output object of `querySelectorAll()`) for various desktop/mobile browsers: http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/e83f68eb169206f5969b6b2a2d3267bd18c520cc *(green = supported, red = not supported)*

A rough compatibility range for passing most array-like objects is: Firefox 4+, Chrome 17+, IE9+, Safari 5.1+ (iPhone 5+/iPad 3+), and Android 2.4+.